# Connect app locally to local Mongo db and on heroku to Mongo Atlas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, heroku, mongoose

I am trying to do the following:

- on local run, my app to connect to my local Mongo database &
- when run on heroku to automatically connect to Mongo Atlas.

So far I have only connected it to Mongo Atlas and I dont know how to do both of them at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use enviroment varialbles.

Define *env* variables in your project using .env.

e.g in `.env` file use

```
DEVELOPMENT=true
```

and check if it's local or Heroku

```
if (process.env.DEVELOPMENT) {
 conenctToLocalDB();
}else{
  connectToAtlas();
}
```

Comment: Should I change something in Dockerfile, I currently have this ENV NODE_ENV=production ?

Comment: No, you dont need to change anything in your Dockerfile

Comment: I did that and it goes straight to Atlas https://prnt.sc/vnv0xj